# Recording in HTML5 does not work in Firefox

Tags: javascript, html, firefox, audio-recording, getusermedia

I am using recorder.js and Recordmp3.js for recording audio through microphone.

It's working fine in chrome browser but not in Firefox(Latest version as well).

When I hit my web app on the Firefox browser, It asks me to share microphone but after few seconds It gets disappeared. So because of that recording feature not be able to record anything on Firefox.

I am sharing on working example developed using Recordmp3.js and It's not working in Firefox.

http://audior.ec/recordmp3js/

Is this a known issue?

Comment: i am using firefox 34 in windows 7, the problem i am getting is, after sometime, the light signalling audio capture disappears and i noticed in that code that ```stream``` reference is not stored anywhere, so this might get garbage collected in firefox hence leading the problem

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I was correct, the problem was audioStream element to garbage collected, I downloaded the code from [github](https://github.com/nusofthq/Recordmp3js) and modified

this:

```
var audio_context;
var recorder;

function startUserMedia(stream) {
    var input = audio_context.createMediaStreamSource(stream);
```

into

```
var audio_context;
var recorder;
var localStream; // line added by me

function startUserMedia(stream) {
    localStream = stream; // line added by me
    var input = audio_context.createMediaStreamSource(stream);
```

hence making sure that the `stream` is not garbage collected.

***P.S*** :

things to note,

1 :   MP3 encoding/decoding technology may be governed by MP3 patents in some countries. For commercial purposes, I would advice you to go for `vorbis/ogg` way( also I think the quality of mp3 after conversion from wav is bad).

2 : I found another problem of extra 50% of silence in the recordings, but the solution for that is already available online if i am correct.

Edit: I have added a demo for this in [github](https://github.com/Mido22/mp3Recorder)

Comment: Now recording is working but whenever I click stop button my Firefox/PC gets hang. Did you face the same issue?

Comment: yes, not exactly hanging, converting to mp3 did take a lot if time.

Comment: But It's working smoothly in chrome.

Comment: sorry, but I have no idea why it is so slow in ff.

Comment: I'm also getting ff hang problem